# Angular & NgRx-Data update & subscription issue

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data, ngrx-data

I'm using Angular 11 & NgRx-Data 10.1.2. I am using the smart component/dumb component pattern.

In my 'list' view when I select an item I route to a detail page passing the item id.

In my detail page, I subscribe to the entity service getByKey()

```
this.siteEntityService.getByKey(this.siteId).subscribe((site: Site) => {
  this.site = site;
});
```

This is the SiteEntityService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EntityCollectionServiceBase, EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory } from '@ngrx/data';
import { Site } from 'src/app/models/site.model';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SiteEntityService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<Site> {
  constructor(serviceElementsFactory: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory) {
    super('Site', serviceElementsFactory);
  }
}
```

When 'edit' is clicked, I open the edit component in a modal:

```
openEditModal(){
  this.showingModal = true;

  this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(SiteEditShellComponent);
  this.modalRef.componentInstance.site = this.site;
}
```

In the Edit component, when the form is submitted is clicked:

```
  formSubmitted(form: any) {
    let updatedSite = { ...this.site };
    updatedSite.name = form.siteName;

    this.siteEntityService.update(updatedSite).subscribe((x: Site) => {
      this.site = x;
      this.activeModal.dismiss();
    })
  }
```

After the update, if I investigate the store I can see that the entity has been updated correctly, however, after the modal has closed, the subscription on the display page doesn't update, despite the store (and the database) updating.

So where am I going wrong? How do I get the display page to refresh the data?

Edited in response to @Fiber's answer:

It's now working, however since the subscription is returning an array of the items, it means that I'm having to search the array for the correct one, which doesn't seem ideal.

```
  loadSite() {
    let sites$ = this.siteEntityService.store.select((new EntitySelectorsFactory().create<Site>('Site')).selectEntities);

    this.subscriptions.add(
      sites$.pipe(
        map((sites: Site[]) => {
          return sites.find((site: Site) => site.id === this.siteId);
        })
      ).subscribe((site: Site) => {
        this.site = site;
      })
    );

    this.siteEntityService.getByKey(this.siteId).subscribe((site: Site) => {
      this.site = site;
    });
  }
```

Comment: What do you have inside `this.siteEntityService.update`?

Comment: I'm using the NgRx-Data (https://ngrx.io/guide/data) module so my siteEntityService is an extension of EntityCollectionServiceBase. I've updated the post to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will fire only once when it retrieves the data from the backend:

```js
this.siteEntityService.getByKey(this.siteId).subscribe((site: Site) => {
  this.site = site;
});
```

That method is connected to the data-retrieve-method, not the entity-store you are seeking.

You should make an observable that connects directly to the store (ngrx/data provides you an EntitySelectorsFactory to be able to do that) and listen to the changes.

```js
// this is gonna fire every time you update the store with new 'Site' items
sites$ = this.store.select((new EntitySelectorsFactory().create<Site>('Site')).selectEntities);

sites$.subscribe((sites: Site[]) => {
  this.site = sites.find(s => s.id === this.siteId);
});

// this will trigger the initial load
this.siteEntityService.getByKey(this.siteId);
```

Obviously the subscriptions should be terminated at component destruction, but skipped that part for brevity.

Comment: I have it working but have a slight query on it, I've updated the post with more information.

Comment: Updated my answer, you are correct I made a mistake - the sites$ observable are returning with an array of Site not just a single one. Your map-filter solution seems a bit crowded, either use a .pipe(map(sites => sites.find(s => s.id === this.siteId))) or filter it in the subscription like in the updated example.

Comment: Updated once more, you don't need the subscription for  `this.siteEntityService.getByKey(this.siteId)` since it will be available trough the store observable anyway.